# WordPress localhost not running

Tags: server, proxy, wordpress

I had installed a LAMP server and WordPress on my Ubuntu machine to run WordPress on localhost. I have done the WordPress setup and got the WP-admin login, but when I get offline and try to run the localhost/WordPress/WP-admin then it shows me following error:

```
Unable to connect
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 192.168.30.225.

The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

localhost runs properly whenever I'm online.

Comment: Have you tried to input the address `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`? As you disconnect, the IP address `192.168.30.225` may get invalid.

Comment: check what you have in wp-config and .htaccess

Comment: Please provide more information. Is the url really `/WordPress/WP-admin/` with all that uppercase letters? At least `wp-admin` should be lowercase. What does the output of `netstat -plnt` show? Is Apache listening on port 80? Do you see any message in the Apache log files? What does your Apache config look like? Can you open the Apache default website?